# Как добавить данные в уже существующую таблицу из файла .sql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Надо добавить данные из файла к существующей таблице... Код ниже добавляет данные из файла `wp_terms.sql`, но переписывает таблицу, если она существует. А мне надо, чтоб к тем записям , которые уже есть , добавились новые из файла . Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо!

```
        $host = "localhost";
        $uname = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $database = "wp_game"; //Change Your Database Name
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $uname, $pass, $database);
        $filename =  plugins_url( 'public/wp_terms.sql' , dirname(__FILE__) )  ; //How to Create SQL File Step : url:http://localhost/phpmyadmin->detabase select->table select->Export(In Upper Toolbar)->Go:DOWNLOAD .SQL FILE
        $op_data = '';
        $lines = file($filename);
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')//This IF Remove Comment Inside SQL FILE
            {
                continue;
            }
            $op_data .= $line;
            if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')//Breack Line Upto ';' NEW QUERY
            {
                $conn->query($op_data);
                $op_data = '';
            }
        }
                echo "Table Created Inside " . $database . " Database.......";
```

Comment: Не включайте в бэкап инструкции пересоздания/очистки таблицы.

Comment: в смысле ?Чет немного не понял

Comment: Вы пишете: *он переписывает таблицу , если она существует*. Показанный код тупо выполняет запросы из .SQL-файла и ничего не делает с таблицей. Значит, в .SQL-файле есть либо DROP TABLE + CREATE TABLE, либо TRUNCATE TABLE. Первое вероятнее. Вот и добейтесь опциями экспорта, чтобы этих команд в файле не было. Либо детектируйте их, как делаете с комментариями, и пропускайте.

Comment: А вообще - надо не в .SQL выгружать таблицу, а в CSV - её данные.

Comment: да, вы правы. Есть в файле DROP+CREATE

Comment: Честно ? не знаю как обойти drop и create функцию, так как эспортом не выход